# Backup using TFS 2010

Tags: .net, sql-server, tfs

Thanks in advance 
I am beginner in .net technology

IS it possible 2010 TFS backup without network path i.e. local drive or USB hard disk?

Comment: Please give some context and use plain English sentences.

Answer (score 2):

First of all check that you have installed the TFS 2010 power Tools.

Take a look at http://myalmblog.com/2010/09/tfs-2010-power-tools-tfs-backup-and-restore-hands-on-lab/

If you want to use a local drive, you just have to "share" it on the network and use the network path. Don't forget to check the folder right (only the backup account should be able to write in this folder, to prevent that somebody delete your backup when you need it...)